# Can’t find in ionic project (<android>/<app>/build.gradle)

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to add Firebase to my android app builded with ionic, the firebase's documentation  https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup says to add this line on my root-level build.gradle.

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}
```

and this line in my module Gradle file (usually the app/build.gradle).

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6'

  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
  // the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

But i can't find app/build.gradle in my ionic projet.

[image]

Where can I find it?

Comment: The guide you linked is for Native Android. The `build.gradle` in your `/platforms/android/` is probably the `build.gradle` it should refer to. The same way the `google-services.json` should be pasted in the `app` folder ([see #5 here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#manually_add_firebase)).

Comment: I have already tried, but it does not work.